# Div inside table auto-size and margins left and right

Tags: html, css, web

I have a table 800px width centered in body html. Inside this table I want to have a DIV, it must have 10px margin-left and 10px margin-right and the rest be 100% the width of the table.

Trying using div width 100% and giving it margin left and right it does not looks good.

Testing again I just gived it margin left and right without giving it a width and it seems like on Chrome the DIV auto-resizes to the full width and giving margins left and right perfect and working good.

The question is if it will really work on all browsers or I was just lucky using Chrome. What is the correct form of doing this?

Because the table is part of my layout I want it there with a div inside just like in the following example:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing Width</title></head><body>

<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td align="center" valign="top">

<div style="background-color:#000000; color:#cccccc; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
Testing auto-size of divs by default. 
Because the table is 800 px and I am not giving the div 
a width does it auto-resize 100% width 
less 10px left and 10px right margin? 
That means also that it alto-resizes to 780px?
</div>
```

This is not a code review. I need help to give it the correct width and margins and make it work on all browsers

EDIT:

What if the table is width 80% and I need the div to be 100% width plus margin left and right 10px?

Comment: By default, a block level element like `div` will auto size to the width of the parent container (taking into account left/right margins).  In this case, the parent container is the table-cell within the 800px wide table.  This should work on all browsers since it is standard CSS.

Comment: Try downloading different browsers and testing yourself. Its the only sure way to make sure code is cross compatible between browsers!

Comment: actually you can `calc` the `width property`: `div{width: calc( 100% - 20px )}`

Comment: maioman so I tried 100% - 20px but what if I the table is liquid width 100% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly in the code section, but for easier development and maintainability, you could use purely CSS-based tables. Also, because a lot of table attributes are deprecated, such as `valign` and `border`, you are better of with standard CSS styling. HTML code:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
            <div class="column">
            Testing auto-size of divs by default. 
            Because the table is 800 px and I am not giving the div 
            a width does it auto-resize 100% width 
            less 10px left and 10px right margin? 
            That means also that it alto-resizes to 780px?
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the related CSS code:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 800px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.column {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You can read about why to use CSS-based tables and how to adjust them from [here](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/).

Comment: I need it to be tables because the site already works like that and tables are working fine on all browsers even cellphones. I edited added in question about liquid table using 80% width the table and div inside the samelike before width 100% - margin right and left. Will it work anyway if the table is liquid 80% width of screen?

Comment: It should work alright but the calc isn't supported by older IE or Android browsers. Just use the 10px margins on div. Anyway, you should test it with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or smth until you find a working solution.